# Solutions to prime power moduli

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to show:

$f(x)=x^2 - 2x$ has precisely two solutions modulo $p^k$ where $p$ is a 0 odd prime, and $k$ is an positive integer.

I'm thinking I need to use Hensel's lemma, and I have shown it is true for $p^2$, but I'm not sure how to continue.

Homework, so hints are what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that we need Hensel's lemma.

Note that $f(x)=x(x-2) \equiv 0 \pmod {p^k}$.

However, note that $p$ cannot divide both $x$ and $x-2$ since $2$ is even and $p$ is odd.

Comment: Can you expand a little?

Comment: Note that $x(x-2) \equiv 0 \pmod {p^k}$ when $x \equiv 0 \pmod {p^{t}}$ and $x \equiv 2 \pmod {p^{k}}$. However, from my answer, $t$ and $k$ cannot both be positive. One has to be $0$.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but the notation of taking the power of the moduli is different to what i'm used to

Comment: @Mark That was just a mistake on my part.